# Cannot access Synology NAS via SMB in different subnetwork

Tags: networking, firewall, nas, cifs

**Summary:**
I have set up a Synology NAS and would like to place it in the basement, next to the cable modem.  My problem is that although I can reach its web UI, CIFS/SMB connections just time out.  This changes as soon as I place the NAS in the living room (different subnetwork), so I suspect that CIFS packets are filtered, but I don't know where.

**Details:**
I use a FRITZ!Box 4040 router in the center of my house for WiFi etc. All regular computers, printer, mobile devices etc. are in the subnetwork of this router (192.168.178.1/24).

This router has a wired LAN connection to the Vodafone cable router in the basement ("Vodafone Station", I don't think I have any valuable hardware details) which manages 192.168.0.1/24.

**Problem Elimination:**
I know that my problem is *not* about name resolution; I have set up local DNS entries in order to access the NAS' web UI ("DSM" 7.1-42661 Update 1), and I can access it both via name and via IP address (in both subnetworks).  I also know that the SMB service runs fine, since I can access shares in one subnetwork, when connecting the NAS to the other router.  I have completely disabled the firewall on the Synology NAS.

Not sure this is helpful, but I tried checking the port status with nmap:

```
% sudo nmap 192.168.0.228 -sU -pU:137-139
Starting Nmap 7.93 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-10-02 16:59 CEST
Nmap scan report for REDACTED (192.168.0.228)
Host is up (0.018s latency).

PORT    STATE         SERVICE
137/udp open|filtered netbios-ns
138/udp open|filtered netbios-dgm
139/udp open|filtered netbios-ssn

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.37 seconds
```

I have read that others run their Synology NAS in a different subnetwork and that it should work in general.

Note that I am trying to connect from MacOS, via `smb://<username>@192.168.0.228` URLs.  (I could try to find a Windows notebook, but I believe this approach to connect should be as robust as others, in particular since I do not rely on any auto-discovery.)

**Questions:**
Do you have any ideas on how to debug this further?  Should I know about some obvious problem / limitation?

Comment: This is hardly about IT managament in a business setting.

Comment: Your nas should have proper routes or default route in routing table

Comment: nmap filtered means this ports blocked by firewall suppously on your router udp protocol is blocked

Comment: @vidarlo do you mean that this was the wrong site to ask on? Sorry, I did not mean to abuse it - which place would you’ve chosen?

Comment: @hans_meine I'd suggest Superuser. I think the question will be migrated there quite soon :)

Comment: IIRC FritzBox routers have just that: A filter for port 445 traffic. It can be toggled in the web UI. _All_ other ports are irrelevant for this question/setup.

Comment: Daniel is right, FritzBox will block outbound SMB connections. Here is a (very old) guide for allowing via config file: http://www.ab-weblog.com/en/open-ports-135-137-and-445-in-avm-fritzbox-routers/

Comment: Thanks a lot, @DanielB and Cpt.Whale – I had searched the FRITZ!Box interface for so long *and* googled for it, albeit not with the helpful "NetBIOS" keyword. If you want to post a real reply, I'd be happy to officially "accept" it. Otherwise, I shall eventually do so myself, for future readers.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Thanks (see above); I think I got distracted after explicitly reading somewhere that FRITZ!Boxes do not do that ("It should work, I have the same setup"), maybe someone forgot that they had to disable that filter. With the right keywords, I now find many posts describing this problem and the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AVM FritzBox routers have a special firewall rule for NetBIOS traffic (even though NetBIOS is no longer the correct term) on ports 139 and 445. Only port 445 is used nowadays and especially when connecting to a target by IP or DNS host name.

The rationale is to protect unwitting users from inadvertently accessing file shares on the internet, potentially subverting regular security measures.

On DSL FritzBox routers you can disable this firewall rule. On cable FritzBox routers, you cannot.

The relevant [KB article 835](https://avm.de/service/wissensdatenbank/dok/FRITZ-Box-7590/835_Datei-und-Druckerfreigaben-eines-Computers-sind-uber-das-Internet-nicht-erreichbar/) is available in German and other languages, including [English](https://en.avm.de/service/knowledge-base/dok/FRITZ-Box-7590/835_Shared-files-and-printers-on-a-computer-are-not-available-over-the-internet/). (Make sure to select the correct router model.)

To deactivate the filter, the guide says this:

> If it is not possible to access the shared files and printers without NetBIOS and the internet service provider does not block NetBIOS, you can disable the NetBIOS filter in the FRITZ!Box instead:
>
> 1. Click "Internet" in the FRITZ!Box user interface.
> 2. Click "Filters" in the "Internet" menu.
> 3. Click on the "Lists" tab.
> 4. Click "Global Filter Settings" to display all of the filter settings.
> 5. Disable the option "NetBIOS filter enabled".
> 6. Click "Apply" to save the settings.

There’s a warning about increased attach surface in the guide. It is, however, *incorrect* or *misleading*. Disabling this filter does not mean *inbound* connections are suddenly allowed.